# Revoking ALTER permissions from users in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, permissions, alter, sql-grant

```
GRANT ALL ON TABLE <table_name> TO <user_name>;
```

The above statement gives permission to a particular user to ALTER the table structures as well to users. How can we restrict the permission of ALTER to tables to users? I want the users only to SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE records rather than allowing them to ALTER the DB structures as well?

Will the below statement help me in achieving my requirement?

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON TABLE <table_name> TO <user_name>;
```

I want the issue related to postgres.

Comment: From the fine manual: "You must own the table to use ALTER TABLE." Just make sure your user isn't the owner, nor a superuser, and the user isn't allowed to alter the table.

Comment: Hi @FrankHeikens, how can I check if my user is allowed to alter the table? I have created a new user and created him CRUD operation access, he is not a superadmin and nor table owner but still able to do alter command. Please help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-grant.html & http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-revoke.html

As you can see `GRANT` and `REVOKE` will do the job.

Suggestion: Keep in mind to use groups for the privileges and handle the assignment by membership to these groups.

Comment: Mere sharing the grant and revoke url's won't help. Atleast please share the commands what he needs to run in order to prevent alter command.